# How to get data form a subclass of the superclass reference? Shape -> rectangle

Tags: java, class

I have `Rectangle` and `Circle` classes. They both extend `Shape`. The class `Object` holds a reference to `Shape`.

Now I want to acces over `object.shape.vertices` if shape is a `Rectangle` or
for `Circle` `object.shape.radius`.

I don't want to save values like radius / vertices etc. in the `Shape` class because radius would never be used in a `Rectangle`.

Comment: You can use `instanceof` to check the type, but that's generally an indicator of poor design.

Comment: Why do you need to access to the internals of the sub classes in your `Object` class (that I strongly suggest to rename immediately)? What's your use case?

Comment: For simple physic calculations. A DebugRenderer needs the vertives or radius to draw... Object would be uset as an Array to iterate truh all objects.

Comment: I guess it will be better to have a `draw(DebugRenderer renderer)` method in `Shape` and do the physic calculations in each subclass rather than letting the external world knows about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `instanceof` operator to check if an object is of a certain type or not, and then cast to that type.

```
double value = 0.0;
if (shape instanceof Circle) {
    Circle circle = (Circle)shape; // Cast the shape to a Circle
    value = circle.radius;
} else {
    // If it's not a circle, then it's a rectangle
    Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle)shape; // Cast the shape to a Rectangle
    value = (double)rectangle.vertices;
}
```

However, usage of the `instanceof` operator should be limited. I would suggest that you instead create a method in the `Shape` class that returns the appropriate field.

```
class Shape {
    public double getValue() {
        return 0.0;
    }
}

class Circle {
    public double radius;
    @Override
    public double getValue() {
        return radius;
    }
}

class Rectangle {
    public int vertices;
    @Override
    public double getValue() {
        return (double)vertices;
    }
}
```

Using the above example, we could shorten the first code example to just

```
double value = shape.getValue();
```

This approach adheres to polymorphism and is ultimately more maintainable, since it's harder to forget to override a method (it would be impossible to forget if you used an abstract method) than to add a new `instanceof` check somewhere else in the code.

If you know about abstract classes and methods, I suggest you make the `Shape` class and its methods abstract.

Comment: Yeah I saw this way but casting does extend the reserved space if the casted type is bigger and Rectangle / Circle should be bigger than Shape. Does this not make a performance lost? EDIT: Yes Shape is abstact becose i need methods like translate in every shape :) Thanks for the great awser!

Comment: @DarioKowalski Casting doesn't change the amount of space used, since the object would already have the size of a circle/rectangle anyway.